# I'm sending to function that return Dialog not all case

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
 public IEnumerable<IResult> Update()
 {
        if (cbUpdateDateFrom)
               yield return UpdateChargePeriodDateFrom(DPUpdateDateFrom);
        if (cbUpdateDateTo)
               yield return UpdateChargePeriodDateTo(DPUpdateDateTo); 
 }
```

now, `UpdateChargePeriodDateFrom()` return `IRESULT` because she need show dialog not in all cases and if don't show dialog return `null`.

The problem, if `UpdateChargePeriodDateFrom()` returns `null` then `Update()` fails-
i'm get error debbuger:Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application: Value cannot be null

what to do?

Comment: What do you mean Update() fails. - What happens? You get an exception? If so, what?

Comment: Someone might be able to help if they knew the context or what those mysterious method calls do excatly. But still I'd suggest you actually DEBUG your code and maybe ask your collegues instead of copy/pasting it here.

Comment: To me this function looks ill-designed. Why do you have to yield from it?

Comment: Worthy as accepted, no?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in a comment, I'd recommend you put more effort in debugging your code. But still, here's something to help you out.

Case being

```
    var func = new Func<IEnumerable<IResult>>(() => null); // return null
    var enumerable = func.Invoke(); // success
    var list = func.Invoke().ToList(); // fail
```

Consider handling the `null` return value outside your method call or modify your logic to return empty `IEnumerable` instead.